# No common file attachments using Android 4.2.2

Tags: email, attachments

I can't seem to attach a simple Word or Excel file using Gmail, Hotmail or a local email client. This is when using the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox and Dolphin browser. Being in China for half a year the only way I can send these files is by attaching them to an email as all webdrive services are blocked in China. Is this a bug or an unwelcome policy of the developers? If it's a bug, is there a way around it? An app or something?

Thank you very much for your responses!

Comment: Have you tried using the GMail or Hotmail apps, rather than the web pages?